# UITableViewCell for iPad

Tags: ios, uitableview, interface-builder, autolayout

I want to create a custom UITableViewCell for my iPad which the frame is 768x400, every time I modified(in interface builder) some items on its subviews, it will RESET the width of  UITableviewCell(superview) to 320. Xib file is iPad family. my custom cells has a lots of subviews and must support autolayout.

Comment: I have the same problem. It seems this has been a problem for a while: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14375552/interface-builder-keeps-reseting-the-width-of-my-custom-uitableviewcell

Comment: @jmathew where you able to get this?

Comment: Unfortunately not, it looks like a bug. I ended up using the inspector for my adjustments, which was annoying but didn't reset everything.

Comment: what you mean is you manually arrange it via inspector? Not touching the view? BTW I really wasn't able how figure out the automatic reset to 320. but my turn around was to programatically code the autolayout..

Comment: In Interface Builder, click the element you want to change. Bring up the right side panel. Click the ruler icon and theres the x,y width, height options. When you change the values there the cell width doesn't reset. But programmatically coding the restraints is better. I couldn't do that because I'm working on an existing project.

Comment: oh! okay, I also did that but it doesn't help me. I think the best for you is to programatically with autolayout as what I did on this and it makes up on me.

Answer (score 0):

Check the source code of the xib (right click on the file -> Open as). In the forum, you can find descriptions what differs between iPhone and iPad (except size). But I would first try to create new file and ensure that the device family is set to iPad. I already had once the problem after copying stuff from an iPhone xib.

Comment: Hi, already check the source code, all are in the same values except the objects inside it, and there all nothing a 320 default width. I already tried creating new file and ensure the family is set to iPad.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the autolayout and make changes in subviews. if you need the autolayout property try to tick autolayout after modification

Comment: Hi, Actually my structure of UITableViewCell is
UITabeViewCell
-UIImage
-UIView

Comment: Hi, Actually my structure of UITableViewCell is
UITabeViewCell(SCView(UIImage,UIView,(SCView(UIView,UIImage))))

I disabled autolayout and put them on their positions, and when I enabled the autolayout. It wont run, it seems there's a lot of error on constraints. I was able to fix and modified their constraints/relationship but the display is not the same as what I was desingning in Interface builder